# Using Parse in .NET MVC site for login and signup and querying objects

Tags: .net, authentication, parse-platform, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I have successfully integrated Parse with an iOS app and I have enjoyed working with it, however it has now come time to build a website for the app that has the same functionality as the iOS app (CRUD operations, User/Access management) and I am having trouble integrating it with an MVC 5 web application. I understand I cannot use the .NET SDK as that will not work for a web site with many concurrent users.

I am lost as to how to proceed. I came across using Owin and .NET Identity and possibly creating custom SignInManager and UserManager implementations where I could then use the Parse .NET SDK methods for performing user login/signup actions but I don't know how this will work since Owin uses cookies and a lot of custom classes would need to be created.

My main question is can this even be done?

Or is the better route to create my own SQL backed user management system and leverage existing OAuth authentication providers already built into Owin like google and facebook.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this nuget package  [Parse.AspNet.Identity](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Parse.AspNet.Identity/) which will help you  if you decided to use  .NET Identity